# Maximum and minimum difference

Tags: javascript

I have written a function that return the maximum and minimum differences of numbers in n given arrays. It seems to work but I want to eliminate zero as the minimum difference. I also want to be able to concatenate more than two arrays incase input has more than two.

```
function maxAndMin(arr1,arr2){
  var maxi =0;
  var mini =0;

  var newarr = arr1.concat(arr2);

  maxi = Math.max.apply(null,newarr)-Math.min.apply(null,newarr);

 newarr = newarr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b; });

   for (var i=0; i<newarr.length; i++){
      if (newarr[i+1] - newarr[i] < mini)
          mini = newarr[i+1] - newarr[i];

   }
   return [maxi, mini];
}
```

Comment: The usual answer would be to make `-Infinity` your initial `maxi` and `Infinity` your initial `mini`, but that won't work with your logic using `sort`.

Comment: Why the loop? Why the sort?

Comment: @t.j.crowder maxi is reset...

Comment: What do you mean "eliminate zero as the min difference"? What should happen in case the min difference is 0?

Comment: I want an absolute value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function maxAndMin(...arr){
  var difference = [];
  arr.reduce((a,b)=>[...a,...b])
   .sort((a,b)=>a-b)
   .reduce((before,now)=>(difference.push(now - before),now),0);
 return [Math.max(...difference)||1,Math.min(...difference)||1];
}
```

You can use a rest parameter to catch all passed arrays in an array. Then you can unify this arrays to one array, sort it, and reduce to the differences. Then simply return the math.max/min of it.
And you can replace 0 with the or operator:

```
0 || 1 => 1
5 || 1 => 5
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/pucalifuro/1/edit?console)

Comment: @hoslack yeah, i will explain when ive finished improving

Comment: What is ...arr?

Comment: Given two array of integers(arr1,arr2). Your task is going to find a pair of numbers(an element in arr1, and another element in arr2), their difference is as big as possible(absolute value); Again, you should to find a pair of numbers, their difference is as small as possible. Return the maximum and minimum difference values by an array: [ max difference, min difference ]

For example:

 Given arr1 = [3,10,5], arr2 = [20,7,15,8]
 should return [17,2] because 20 - 3 = 17, 10 - 8 = 2

Comment: That's the description